# Advanced search : how to apply wildcardFilter for custom attribute

Tags: magento2

I have added some custom product attribute to advance search if I search for lower case letter then all work, but when I search using capital letter then it does not give any result.

the same thing is working for SKU search, but not working for another attribute.

so I review the code at vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/etc/search_request.xml and found that

```
<filter xsi:type="wildcardFilter" name="sku_query_filter" field="sku" value="$sku$"/>
```

**wildcardFilter** is applied for the SKU attribute.

So my question is how we can apply the same for custom-created attributes and attribute type if textarea.